# WebRTC: Multiparty Video Conference

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, voip, video-conferencing

Im trying to set up a multi party video conference using WebRTC and just need a little clarification on something:

Q) Do I need to have an `RTCPeerConnection` object for each member of the conference or just one?

For example, I am currently doing this for two way communication which works well...

```
var pc; // single peer connection instance (see startPeerConnection)

startLocalVideo(function (stream) {
    //Offer Local video to Remote Server
    if (stream) {
        if (!pc) {
            startPeerConnection();
        }
        if (pc) {
            pc.addStream(stream);
            pc.onaddstream = addRemoteStream;
            pc.createOffer(function (description) {
                pc.setLocalDescription(description, function () {
                    signal('offer', {
                        extension: extension,
                        call: currentcall,
                        description: description
                    });
                }, failure);
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("createOffer error: " + error);
            });
        }
    }

});

function startPeerConnection() {
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection({
        iceServers: [{
            url: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
        }]
    });
    pc.onicecandidate = gotLocalIceCandidate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to create a multiparty call using a mesh network, where all participants send their media to all the rest of the participants. You will need to create a peer connection object for every endpoint in the call.